# What is the maximum date python can store?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, limit

Using python datetime module:
`from datetime import date`
what is the farthest in the future I can go while being sure I won't break anything?

Comment: you can look yourself by printing out [`datetime.date.max`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.max)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.max):

> The latest representable date, date(MAXYEAR, 12, 31).

But, what is `MAXYEAR`? Well, is **the largest year number allowed in a date or datetime object**: `9999`

So, the larger date that you can reach is `12/31/9999`